Dynamic Datasource in Paginated Power BI Reports
I need directions to the possibilty of having a Power BI paginated Report were I can switch the databases via URL parameters.
I created a report with two Parameters a) ServerName b)DatabaseName, when I publish it I am unable to proceed further.
As explained above, it seems to miss some steps.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
